# Obfuscating Swift code before submission to Apple App Store

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, obfuscation

I'm having a hard time finding any info on this. Android themselves mention code obfuscation as something to do before submitting to their store. But I see nothing about this from Apple or from any "third party" before-submission checklists. The only similar question I could find was one 5 years ago about Objective-C, and I only can find 1 github library about iOS obfuscation. Is it a common practice to obfuscate Swift code when submitting to the Apple App Store? Especially to hide any private API URLs or API keys? Is there a Pro-Guard equivalent for Apple?

Answer (score 31):

Java gets converted into bytecode, which can be decompiled.

Swift is a compiled language, and the Clang compiler is highly optimized. In release mode it strips out symbols and does a lot of optimization that does a great deal of obfuscation all by itself. There are decompilers for compiled languages, but the results are really awful and hard to read.

### Edit:

There are tools like iXGuard that have the ability to further obfuscate your Swift code, making it even harder for hackers to reverse-engineer it.

Comment: Actually, Xcode also converts Swift code into a kind of intermediate representation bytecode, called bitcode by Apple.  But, IIRC, bitcode gets stripped out by Apple before sending an app to customers, and the app's compiled code is also encrypted by Apple.  The optimizations performed by the Swift compiler on a Release Build (including code re-ordering, etc.) performs some amount of obfuscation.

Comment: @hotpaw2, I don't think it's true that the app's compiled code is encrypted. It's code-signed, and the target device's OS refuses to launch the app unless the signature (which includes the user's AppleID) checks out.

Comment: Download an app from the iOS App store and see if you can find any ARM machine code visible in the zip file.

Comment: so do I not need to worry about hiding API keys and private RESTful API URLs?

Comment: @Kardinal A RESTful api by itself shouldn't contain any private URL's. Following the HATEOAS principle you should only need the root of the api, thus one url, to access all other resources. In general you should try to put any security mechanism in the backend as client based security does not work. Even if one only gets the pure machine code of the app one could reverse engineer the urls. (may take some effort though) Everything a client knows can theoretically be extracted, with enough knowledge and time. Just secure your endpoints.

Comment: What do you think about "swiftshield"? They say they obfuscate the code. Is it unnecessary, since it's already stripped and optimized?

Answer (score 7):

A bit late to the party, but plain text strings can be extracted with no need of a jailbroken device just issuing the command strings to your executable.

So, yes, protect your sensitive strings in some way.

You can check my command line utility for doing this:

https://github.com/pabloroca/obfuscateapi