# How to obfuscate cocoa touch framework codes? (swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, obfuscation

I'm working on `Payment Framework` (using `swift` 4) and i don't want apps can see or change my code
something like obfuscation in android
How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Obfuscating Swift code before submission to Apple App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802157/obfuscating-swift-code-before-submission-to-apple-app-store)