# Obfuscation Swift code before submission to Apps store

Tags: swift, obfuscation

Hello all how can obfuscation the swift code to prevent reverse engineer of IPA?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Obfuscating Swift code before submission to Apple App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802157/obfuscating-swift-code-before-submission-to-apple-app-store)

Comment: If you want to be protected against other people copying your idea, register it as a patent. If your security depends on obscurity: [Kerckhoff's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using swift shield CLI to obfuscate swift code. Automatic mode doesn't seem production ready to me as it has few issues with CoreData files obfuscation. Manual mode works well, Although it is time consuming task to add tags to your class/method/property names.

https://github.com/rockbruno/swiftshield

Comment: This project cannot be used to submit apps, the author writes: "Don't use this tool for production apps"